# Task Completed Event does not triggers in OOB Approval Workflow SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, approval-process

When I approve a Task using JSOM code it doesn't triggers "When Task is Completed" step in approval workflow.  But when I approve it through OOB InfoPath form, it does triggers and send the mails as expected.

Below is the code that I used to approve a task:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var tasksList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");
var task = tasksList.getItemById(itemId);

task.set_item("Status", "Completed");
task.set_item("Completed","TRUE");
task.set_item("PercentComplete", 1);    
task.set_item("WorkflowOutcome",outcome);

task.update();
```

I verified the Task attributes after execution of above code. All of them are getting updated as expected.

My question is, do I need to update some any other fields of Task to trigger it  or it's not at all possible through custom code?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and hits, I got to know that, **It's not possible with REST or JSOM.**
You need to set **TasskStatus** to **Completed** which we can not set using REST.
It is Possible using Server Side Code:

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable["Status"] = "Complete";
hashTable["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
hashTable["TaskStatus"] = "#";//#- Approved and @- Rejected

SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((taskedit as SPListItem), hashTable, true);
```

Post execution of this code, it will resume WF and enters the **Completed** state.